# Logon Trigger for auditing

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Using SQL Server 2008R2

I am working on a LOGON trigger to capture users who have logged in.  I have created a trigger, but it is capturing the SQL Agent account and is inserting it like mad.  I would like to exclude it from the list, but I'm not sure how to modify the trigger to make it so.  The different attempts locked me out and I had to use DAC to drop the trigger.

The original code:

```
USE B_DBA;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER LogonTrigger ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS 
BEGIN
    IF SUSER_SNAME() <> 'sa'
    INSERT INTO B_DBA.dbo.LogonAudit (UserName, LogonDate, spid) 
            VALUES (SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE(), @@SPID)
END;
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER LogonTrigger ON ALL SERVER;
```

What I'd like to add is basically a where clause, but I haven't been able to add it successfully and it would not work on the IF section.

```
Where not in (Select service_account from sys.dm_server_services)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If your application authenticates its users, but uses a single SQL Server account to access the database, then the application will need to log the authentication.

Comment: There is no application involved.  I am simply inserting every user that logs into the database.  This will be on multiple servers which is why I need the dynamic where, not a static account.

Comment: @H.Fadlallah Note that the [tag:sql] tag is only for questions where  answers should use ISO/IEC standard SQL (you can read this in the pop-up for the tag). No answer to this question could possibly be in standard SQL. The [tag:tsql] tag is for T-SQL answers.

Comment: Thank you and my apologies.  I have removed the SQL tag.

Comment: Oh :) the comment was directed to the editor that added the SQL tag, not you. No need to apologize!

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but it seems like you should be able to modify your IF statement to check `sys.dm_server_services`:

```
USE B_DBA;
GO

CREATE TRIGGER LogonTrigger ON ALL SERVER FOR LOGON
AS 
BEGIN
    IF SUSER_SNAME() <> 'sa'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT service_account FROM sys.dm_server_services WHERE service_account = SUSER_SNAME())
    INSERT INTO B_DBA.dbo.LogonAudit (UserName, LogonDate, spid) 
            VALUES (SUSER_SNAME(), GETDATE(), @@SPID)
END;
GO
ENABLE TRIGGER LogonTrigger ON ALL SERVER;
```

Comment: I agree that is SHOULD work, but I tested your script and it is still adding that System Agent account to the table.

Comment: @bwilliamson - do the account names in `sys.dm_server_services` match the names being logged in your audit table?

Comment: They do. Service account is Prod\SQLname.  Entry in the table is Prod\SQLname. ( names altered to protect the innocent. )